# Tag Facebook friends in a status on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, tags, fbconnect

I have used the following code to get user's friend list:

```
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=%lld )",appDelegate.session.uid];
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
```

And I want to tag friends in my status post. I know this can be achieved by Facebook Graph api-

```
@[{user_id}:1:{name}]
```

But I don't know how to implement this. No idea. Can anyone please guide me how to implement this Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't tag users like this using the Graph API. The functionality you're looking for is a feature limited to the Facebook website only.